# How do I display even intervals on both axes using matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

This code plots the data exactly as I want with the dates on the x-axis and the times on the y-axis. However I want the y-axis to show every hour on the hour (e.g., 00, 01, ... 23) and the x-axis to show the beginning of every month at an angle so there's no overlap (the actual data being used spans over a year) and only once, since this code repeats the same months. How is this accomplished?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data = ['2018-01-01 09:28:52', '2018-01-03 13:02:44', '2018-01-03 15:30:27', '2018-02-04 11:55:09']

f, ax = plt.subplots()
data = pd.to_datetime(data, yearfirst=True)
ax.plot(data.date, data.time, '.')
ax.set_ylim(["00:00:00", "23:59:59"])

days = mdates.DayLocator()
d_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(d_fmt) 

plt.show()
```

UPDATE: This fixes the x axis.

```
# Monthly intervals on x axis
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
d_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m') 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(d_fmt)
```

However, this attempt to fix the y axis just makes it blank.

```
# Hourly intervals on y axis
hours = mdates.HourLocator()
t_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(t_fmt)
```

I'm reading these docs but not understanding my error: https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html, https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I don't know how to format the y axis to show every hour on the hour. As for the x axis, if you run the script, it repeats the same month again and again. There must be a way to prevent that so it only shows each month once.

Comment: For monthly ticks, use an `MonthLocator`, for hourly ticks use an `HourLocator`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I got the x axis to display properly. Still stuck on the y axis. See update.

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. There is a clear problem in the question, which can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib cannot plot times without corresponding date. This would make is necessary to add some arbitrary date (in the below case I took the 1st of january 2018) to the times. One may use `datetime.datetime.combine` for that purpose.

```
timetodatetime = lambda x:dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(2018, 1, 1), x)
time = list(map(timetodatetime, data.time))

ax.plot(data.date, time, '.')
```

Then the code from the question using `HourLocator()` would work fine. Finally, setting the limits on the axes would also require to use `datetime` objects,

```
ax.set_ylim([dt.datetime(2018,1,1,0), dt.datetime(2018,1,2,0)])
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

data = ['2018-01-01 09:28:52', '2018-01-03 13:02:44', '2018-01-03 15:30:27', 
        '2018-02-04 11:55:09']

f, ax = plt.subplots()
data = pd.to_datetime(data, yearfirst=True)
timetodatetime = lambda x:dt.datetime.combine(dt.date(2018, 1, 1), x)
time = list(map(timetodatetime, data.time))

ax.plot(data.date, time, '.')

# Monthly intervals on x axis
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
d_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m') 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(d_fmt)

## Hourly intervals on y axis
hours = mdates.HourLocator()
t_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(t_fmt)

ax.set_ylim([dt.datetime(2018,1,1,0), dt.datetime(2018,1,2,0)])

plt.show()
```

[image]